# changing the date on sql

Tags: sql

I wanted to change the date on the database but I found in a weird type of numbers let's say I want to change it to 1/15/2021 how to do that?
Thanks

[database][image: 1]

Comment: which dbms are you using? is it MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the fields `odate` and `odate2` are in unix_timestamp data types.
So, if you are using MySQL database, you can format it as follow:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1568253910), '%m/%d/%Y') AS mydate;
-- output: '09/11/2019'
```

You just need to overwrite the explicit value `1568253910` with your column, and specify the table.

But if you need to change all values directly in the table, so you can do:

```sql
UPDATE database.table SET odata = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(odata), '%m/%d/%Y');
UPDATE database.table SET odata2 = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(odata2), '%m/%d/%Y');
```

See also: [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)